# jquery select nearest select box to add select options

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two select boxes in  separate table cells. when i select the option in first select box related values will put from db. Now i need to append this value to immediate select box (having the class name of getpopltddocname). My HTML looks like below:

```
<tr>
    <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle">Doc Group</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <select id="docgroupname_doc[]" name="docgroupname_doc[]" class="populatedocname" tabindex="1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Doc</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Bank</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">Doc Name</td>
    <td class="makeselect" align="left" valign="middle">
        <select id="docname_doc[]" name="docname_doc[]" class="getpopltddocname" tabindex="1">
            <option value="">Select Doc Name</option>            
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my Jquery code:

```
$(document).on("change",".populatedocname",function(){
    var docid=$(this).val();
    var sel = $(this).closest('td').next().find('select');

    $.post("classes/ajax.php", {action:'getdocitem',docid:docid},function(data) {
        alert(data);
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].doc_item_id + '">' + data[i].doc_name + '</option>');
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: Is the `el` variable name in the line inside the loop a typing mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `parent` like

```
var sel = $(this).parent('td').find('select');
```

Or you can also try like

```
var sel = $(this).parent('td').find('select');
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrXkn/)

**EDIT :** As if you want to append option then it should be like

```
var sel = $(this).parent('td').find('select option');
```

**FINAL :** Finally got solution for my problem..

```
var sel = $(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').find('select');
```

Comment: Thank You.. It's working.. but unable append a select option... That's my actual need...

Comment: Finally i got solution with help of @Gautam3164
Here is what am using now..
`var sel = $(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').find('select');`
Thank You very much....

Answer (score 0):

Additional try the find() function

e.g

```
$('your-selector').find('select');
```

Comment: No its not working.. Hope you saw the select box is an array.. table row is looping in php. I need to append value to immediate select box after the first select box in every row.